# MongoDB and PHP connection

Tags: php, mongodb

I am trying to use MongoDB with **php5.6** on **Ubuntu 16.04**. I have a php script that creates a collection. When i open the script on my Apache Web server, it says "connection successful, collection created" but when i login in the mongo terminal and switch to the database(ecoss), i can't find the collection.

To make the connection: i installed the mongoDB extension by running `sudo apt-get update` and `sudo apt-get install php5.6-mongo`

Afterwards i edited my **php.ini** file and added the extension `extension=mongo.so;`

Installation of php-mongo:

[image]

Extract of my php.ini file:

[image]

Here is my php script `create.php`

```
<?php

    // connect to mongodb
    $m = new MongoClient();

    $db = $m->ecoss;    
    echo "Connection successful, Database ecoss selected" . "<br>";

    $collection = $db->createCollection("mycol");
    echo "Collection created succsessfully";

?>
```

After executing the above script, output on my browser:

[image]

Output on mongo terminal after connecting to **ecoss** database and running the command `show collections` :

[image]

Comment: Mongo does not create collections until necessary. You don't pass any special options to `createCollection`, so there's no specific need for Mongo to create the collection. It will be created implicitly the first time you try to insert data. I'm not *sure* whether this is the reason Mongo doesn't create the collection, but it seems plausible.

Comment: I tried to create a collection on mongo terminal without passing any options or inserting data. After running show collections, i could see my newly created collection. That's why i can't understand why it is not working on php.

Comment: Can you dump `$collection` after you execute createCollection and see what it returned?

Comment: @eselskas hey it is returning ecoss.mycol . That could mean something!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My problem has been solved!

When creating a new collection through php, the collection will be created. Thanks to @eselskas i saw that when dumping `$collection`, it returned **ecoss.mycol**. 
The problem is that the collection won't appear on mongo shell after connecting to the database **ecoss** and running the command `show collections`. This is due to authentication problems with **php** accessing **mongo**.

Below are the steps that helped me to solve this problem:

1. Connect to admin database with `use admin`
2. Drop the admin database `db.dropDatabase()`
3. Remove `--auth` in the file **mongod.service** `sudo nano /lib/systemd/system/mongod.service`. The line **ExecStart** should appear as `ExecStart=/usr/bin/mongod --quiet --config /etc/mongod.conf` (after removing `--auth`)
4. Run the command `sudo systemctl daemon-reload` and `sudo systemctl restart mongod` to reload the service.

After the above steps, i run my `create.php` script, and logged in mongo and my database **ecoss** then made `show collections`, i could clearly see my collection **mycol**.

Comment: Glad you got it sorted!